# Searching and then replacing entire lines with variables in a txt file using a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a .bat file that will substitute a set of variables (in order) with an entire line of text.

I have used to pull a array of 3 lines of text from the file 'variables.txt':

```
    @echo off
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set vidx=0
    for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (variables.txt) do (
SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
set var!vidx!=%%A
    )
    set var
```

I want to scan the file 'export.txt' and, the first time it hits the word 'client' I want to replace that entire line with the first variable.

The second time it hits the word 'client' I want it to replace the entire line with the second variable (and so on).

I'm really having a hard time and am not sure about multiple variable in the for /F sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you just need to cycle through the lines containing `client`

```
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr "client" export.txt') do (
SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
set var!vidx!=%%A
)
set var
```

for export.txt file:

```
blah
client test1 test1
blah blah blah
client test2 test 2
blah blah
blah
test client test3
```

output is:

```
var1=client test1 test1
var2=client test2 test 2
var3=test client test3
```